# Mac App in App Store with sandbox. Entitlements rejected by review

Tags: macos, appstore-approval, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

[image][image]

> 2. - 4 Performance: Hardware Compatibility
>
> Performance - 2.4.5
>
> Your app uses still one or more entitlements which do not have matching functionality within the app. Apps should have only the minimum set of entitlements necessary for the app to function properly. Please remove all entitlements that are not needed by your app and submit an updated binary for review, including the following:
>
> `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write`
>
> It is not appropriate to predetermine the path that the user may have their files located.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has indicated it is not in their judgement that your application requires reading or writing in the Downloads folder without user specification.

Disabling the `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write` will still allow users to save and open files located in their Downloads folder through standard interfaces (`NSOpenPanel`, `NSSavePanel`).

Note that it will disable your application from saving and opening *arbitrary* files in the Downloads folder without first being selected by the user.